# Paperclip Error while uploading image from mobile application

Tags: android, paperclip, image-uploading

I am getting following error when uploading image from mobile application

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20120504-12074-1wgc6pp.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/stream20120504-12074-1wgc6pp.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

In my config/environments/development.rb

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"

The main problem is that When I tried to upload image from web it's working fine.But when I tried to upload image from mobile application(android) it gives above error.I am sending .json request from mobile application.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!!!!
Thank you..

Comment: I already tried 1) apt-get install imagemagick.
2) apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
3) gem install rmagick

Comment: Can you at least post what the JSON request looks like (or the code you use to generate the JSON request)?